# How to create json given below in java?

Tags: java, json

How can I create json given below?

```
{
    "data": [{"id":"some value", 
    "name":"some value"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Hi! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. Be sure to mention which JSON library you're using (there are several). People will be glad to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create a nested json in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578092/how-to-create-a-nested-json-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on your JSON lib, but with org.json.simple or net.sf.json it would be something like this:

```
JSONObject objectInArray = new JSONObject();
objectInArray.put("id", "some value");
objectInArray.put("name", "some value");
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.add(objectInArray);
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data.put("data", jsonArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gson-2.x.jar from google
make a entity class like

```
public class MyEntity{
    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<Data> m_listData;

   //Setter getters
   public List<Data> getData() {
        return m_listData;
    }

    public void setData(List<Data> data) {
        this.m_listData= data;
    }
}
class Data{
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id= id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }
}

//and then convert you json string to java object
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){

       String jsonString="your JSON string"
       Gson obj_gson = new Gson();
       MyEntity obj_myEntity=obj_gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyEntity.class);
  }
}
```